# encoding json using webrequest

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest

i am using this code to get json data

```
public static string GetAllScores(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    try
    {
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
        using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

the data is coming back and everything ok beside the data returning with Ã© . i try lot of other users solution but nothing so far

[image]

Comment: You could take a look at the content-type header to see the actual encoding used, instead of assuming that it's UTF-8.

Comment: the data is returning that way from the API (also in the manufacture website)

Comment: I guess you don't really need to specify encoding since UTF8 is the default of StreamReader. Also you can use ReadAsStringAsync or you should try to check if the API is returning data well.